# Failed ssh sttempt via Ansible

Tags: linux, ssh, ansible

```
fatal: [SW1]: FAILED! => {"ansible_facts": {"discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python3"}, "changed": false, "msg": "paramiko: The authenticity of host '<ip-address>' can't be established.\nThe ssh-rsa key fingerprint is b'11cf4d805165c66aaa56245674095d3f3'."}
```

I am new to Ansible and trying to explore it, I am facing an issue while connecting to the switch via ansible playbook, but while I ssh to ip address using terminal I am able to login in.

Things I tried:

1. I made the `host_key_checking = False` in `ansible.cfg`
2. Added the Algorithm and cipher entries in .ssh/config file
3. Disabled `ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no admin@<ip-address>`

Kindly help.

Comment: This looks like a regular ssh issue. Can you login from the Ansible host to the switch?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to access a network switch, they won't have a python interpreter, so you will need to use the `raw` module (`ansible-doc raw`).

As for your access issues, try using the `raw` module first. After that, take a look at common SSH troubleshooting.